# Google sheets, get a single value from a function that returns a table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use `=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&"USD"&"GBP", "price",TODAY()-1)` to output just the exchange rate yesterday.

It currently outputs four cells like this

| Date | Close |
| --- | --- |
| 31/01/2021 23:58:00 | 0.73002 |

I basically just want the `0.73002` value from this.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en):

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:"&"USD"&"GBP", "price",TODAY()-1),2,2)
```

[image]